# mysql : How to order by string in records with mixed data?

Tags: mysql

Here is the sql fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1b9206/2  . I need to arrange and fetch these records in an order so that it display in this order `starter, pro5, pro9, pro14, pro18, pro24, pro31, pro46, pro62, MaxPro.` How can i achieve this order with mysql or PHP ?
In PHP I am sending the results of the following query as an array:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(name, ' - ', detail) AS name, price FROM am_membership_packages WHERE package = 'monthly' ORDER BY id ASC
```

I have tried different tricks as it can be seen in fiddle but nothing worked.

Comment: The issue is that `name` is a varchar and a `pro18` comes before `pro5` in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order it by price ascending it gives you the order you are looking for.

`ORDER BY price ASC;`

Comment: I am such an idiot i didn't see price. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Haroon if you add more and different types of products can you guarantee you'll always want to order them by price? That wasn't your original intention, although coincidentally it happens to be true that it achieves your desired order, based on the current data.

Comment: yes @ADyson all products are named and ordered on basis of price

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to add a column called `display_index` to the `am_membership_packages` table, then do `ORDER BY display_index` in the query.
  When populating the `display_index` column it can be useful to skip numbers.  For instance, if `id` 1 is to appear first, then enter 10 in the `display_index`.  If a new membership package is entered in the future that needs to appear before the membership package with `id` 1, then the `display_index` of the new package could be entered as 5 and no renumbering would be needed in `display_index` for the other rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing inherent in those names which would allow you to order them in the required way. I suggest simply adding another column called (for example) `DisplayOrder` which is an integer.

Set the values such that they will be displayed in the sequence you want when you `ORDER BY DisplayOrder` in your query.

Comment: Yes there is. The price is in that order.

Comment: @ChipDean arguably a coincidence, although given the nature of the products currently shown it's quite likely they'll always be priced in that order. That might not, however, hold true if more and different types of products are added...

Comment: He's not asking about all products. He has a specific list he needs in a certain order.

Comment: @ChipDean also, technically, I said "There's nothing inherent in those **names**"...so the statement itself is true.

Comment: @ChipDean you still don't know if more "monthly" products wouldn't be added where he might want to order it in a way that happens not to reflect the price. It fixes it for now, but I'm not convinced it's a good idea to rely on it.

Comment: Lol ok Buddy... Have a nice day.

Comment: @ChipDean Your comment wasn't strictly accurate about the statement I made, that's all. Pedantry? Yes, and no doubt amusing if you have nothing better to laugh at. But programming is all about accuracy and detail. So is language. And language informs programs (e.g. through requirements) in such a way that inaccuracy or ambiguity causes big problems. So I make no apology for pointing out linguistic issues. If you're going to call out what I wrote, be sure you have fully absorbed exactly what I was writing about.